# Digit numbers $\times 2$

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

Some cute results have every digit doubled.

\begin{align}
99225500774400 = {} & \frac{40!}{31!} \\[8pt]
33554433 = {} & 2^{25} +1 \\[8pt]
222277 = {} & -22^{2^2}+77^3 \\[8pt]  
8811551199 = {} & 95^5 + 64^5 \\[8pt]
7755660000 = {} & 95^5 + 65^4 \\[8pt]
334444448888 = {} & 6942^3 - 10^8 \\[8pt]
11881133 = {} & 26^5 - 3^5 \\[8pt]
0.0011223344556677\ldots = {} & \frac 1 {891} \\[8pt]
22116600446655008888446677444 = {} & 148716510336462^2 \\[8pt]
\end{align}

The last is from [A079036](http://oeis.org/A079036).  What are other cute examples?

Comment: $1/891$ isn't quite all that: $0.\overline{001122334455667789}$. (But cute nonetheless!)

Comment: do you have a question that can be fully answered in one answer post?  If not, and you're trying to create a big-list, than you should flag a moderator to make the post Community-Wiki.  Else, the question will be closed as off topic, or appropriately, as too broad.

Comment: Flag a moderator?  How?

Comment: Click "flag" then "in need for moderator intervention" then explain what you need.

Comment: A few examples:

$$11223344 = 15^6 - 409^2;\\
44554455 = 82^4 - 811^2;\\
11115555 = (3333+1)^2 - 1;$$

$$2255335577 = 1001^3 + 66^5;\\
6655114466 = 1881^3 - 55^3;$$

$$116699226688 = 4888^3 - 444^3;\\
999988884444 = (9999+1)^3 - (3333+1)^2;$$

$$88448844110066 = 831^3 + 44555^3;\\
22117799114433 = 8820^3 + 27777^3;$$

$$2233665511665533 = 96773^3 + 6036^4;$$

$$11334455660044117700 = 58023^4 - 10981^3.$$

Comment: And few examples with doubled digits in LHS & RHS: $$7744 = 88^2;\\
8833 = 88^2 + 33^2;\\
99115577 = 22^3 + 88^4 + 33^5;\\
99665522 = 1199^2+9911^2;\\
8866887744 = 1144^3 + 22^6 + 44^6;\\
225500447744 = (77^2 + 55^3) * 1144^2;\\
22448822990088 = 2244^2 + 2200^4 - 9922^3;\\
2255447744002299 = 119977^3 + 3355^4 + 4477^4;\\
994466559944559944 = 9944^4 + 669922^3 + 881100^3.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac15=0.001100110011\ldots_2\;,$$

$$\frac1{20}=0.001100110011\ldots_3\;,$$

and generally

$$\frac1{101(10-1)}=0.001100110011\ldots$$

in all bases.

Comment: This one crosses over from cute to beautiful.

Comment: @user21820: Thanks! I was missing a factor $10-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2244}{9999}=0.\overline{2244}$$
$$\frac{22446688}{10^8-1}=0.\overline{22446688}$$
$$\frac{112233445566778899}{10^{18}-1}=0.\overline{112233445566778899}$$
$$\frac{2}{909}=0.\overline{0022}$$
$$\frac{1133}{9999}=0.\overline{1133}$$

$$\frac{1}{11}=0.\overline{09}$$

Comment: Cool-looking ... but the only doubled digit I see is $11$.

Comment: okay I removed the other two examples

Comment: I tried to create some examples using old-school math trick :P

Comment: But here you're putting the doubling of the digits into the input by design, so that's not as good. And similarly with "joriki" 's examples.

Comment: nice so you downvoted me but did not downvote @joriki also OP has not mentioned any restrictions  he just asked for some examples